# How to join some (not all) array elements based on condition in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Say I have an array of strings like this:

```
array = ["foo", "(bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp", "(derp)"]
```

And I need to join items starting with "(" with the previous item to get output like this:

```
["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
```

I guess it has to be something like get indices of array items that match `/^\(/` and then iterate over original array in a block, joining items at `index-1..index`, and deleting at `index`

Comment: Good question, well-stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.slice_before{|s| !s.start_with?("(")}.map{|a| a.join(" ")}
# => ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
```

Comment: @sawa thanks! Actually I don't really like `!` operator and prefer `a.slice_before{|s| /^[^\(]/.match s}.map{|a| a.join(" ")}`

Comment: Why do you not like it? If you do not like preposing it, which indeed looks exceptional, then you can write it as an ordinary method like `s.start_with?("(").!` (which is the way I write), but I didn't write so because almost always someone will complain somehow.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at it from another direction - joining the whole string, then splitting it along spaces which do not have `(` after them:

```
array.join(' ').split(/ (?!\()/)
# => ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if some of the elements would contain a space. sawa's approach is better.

Comment: @DavidUnric I know this is old but I think you are missing the point. You can always make a more obvious marker instead of space that makes sure you don't have collisions like that, for example say that the `marker = "[+MARKER+]"` then you could just do `array.join.split(/#{marker}(?!\()/)`, I truly love ruby for letting me just insert variables into regexes like that. You can also replace the `"\("` part with whatever marker and add it to a variable also

Answer (score 2):

I cannot improve upon @sawa's answer, but I can offer an alternative approach that some readers may find useful at another time in another place:

```
array = ["foo", "(bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp", "(derp)"]

arr = []
enum = array.each
loop do
  arr << enum.next
  next_up = enum.peek
  if next_up[0] == ?(
    arr[-1] += (" " + next_up)
    enum.next
  end
end

arr #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
```

This is what's happening.

```
arr = []
enum = array.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["foo", "(bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp", "(derp)"]:each>
```

Let's now step through the loop until a `StopIteration` exception is raised:

```
s = enum.next                #=> "foo"
arr << s                     #=> ["foo"]
next_up = enum.peek          #=> "(bar)"
next_up[0] == ?(             #=> true
  arr[-1] += (" " + next_up) #=> "foo (bar)"
    arr                      #=> ["foo (bar)"]
  enum.next                  #=> "(bar)" (discard)

s = enum.next                #=> "baaz"
arr << s                     #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz"]
next_up = enum.peek          #=> "quux"
next_up[0] == ?(             #=> false

s = enum.next                #=> "quux"
arr << s                     #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux"]
next_up = enum.peek          #=> "herp"
next_up[0] == ?(             #=> false

s = enum.next                #=> "herp"
arr << s                     #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp"]
next_up = enum.peek          #=> "(derp)"
next_up[0] == ?(             #=> true
  arr[-1] += (" " + next_up) #=> "herp (derp)"
    arr                      #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
  enum.next                  #=> "(derp)" (discard)

s = enum.next                #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

The `StopIteration` exception is handled by [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking the loop.

```
arr                          #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, using [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk). I assume that the first character of the first element of the array is not `(`, but the method could of course be modified if that assumption is not correct.

**Code**

```
def doit(array)  
  array.chunk { |s| s[0] == ?( }
       .map(&:last)
       .each_slice(2)
       .map { |arr| (arr.size == 2) ? [arr.first[0..-2],
                      [arr.first.last, *arr.last].join(' ')] : arr }
       .flatten
end
```

**Examples**

```
array = ["foo", "(bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp", "(derp)"]
doit(array) #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]

array = ["foo", "(bar)", "(anther bar)", "quux"]    
doit(array) #=> ["foo (bar) (anther bar)", "quux"]
```

**Explanation**

```
array = ["foo", "(bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp", "(derp)"]

enum1 = array.chunk { |s| s[0] == ?( }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000101142ce0>:each>

enum1.to_a # elements to be enumerated (for information only)
  #=> [[false, ["foo"]], [true, ["(bar)"]],
  #    [false, ["baaz", "quux", "herp"]], [true, ["(derp)"]]]
a = enum1.map(&:last)
  #=> [["foo"], ["(bar)"], ["baaz", "quux", "herp"], ["(derp)"]]
enum2 = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["foo"], ["(bar)"], ["baaz", "quux", "herp"],
  #                  ["(derp)"]]:each_slice(2)>
enum2.to_a # elements to be enumerated (for information only)
  #=> [[["foo"], ["(bar)"]], [["baaz", "quux", "herp"], ["(derp)"]]]
c = enum2.map { |arr| (arr.size==2) ? [arr.first[0..-2],
                        [arr.first.last, *arr.last].join(' ')] : arr }
  #=> [[[], "foo (bar)"], [["baaz", "quux"], "herp (derp)"]]
c.flatten
  #=> ["foo (bar)", "baaz", "quux", "herp (derp)"]
```